# How to set an angle to an imageview in xml

Tags: android

I am working in an android application and I want to set my image view in a particular angle in the xml itself. How can I do this ? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

On Honeycomb end newer SDK you can do it in XML like this:

```
android:rotationX="10dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way. It to use a [RotateDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RotateDrawable.html). Google documentation is quite poor, but the feature is very pratical to use. To acomplish what you want just do this:

1 - Create your Rotate drawable in a XML drawable file:

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="120"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:drawable="@drawable/myImageIwantToRotate"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="360"/>
```

Notice the "fromDegrees". That is the angle you want your image to rotate when it`s loaded. If you dont want to animate or rotate programatically you dont need to worry about the "toDegrees" parameter.

2 - Add that to your activity layout just like you would add a regular image, but instead select the XML file you just created (step 1) as the src:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/myDrawableXMLfileName"
    android:id="@+id/myRotatedImageID" />
```

**IMPORTANT:**The Rotate drawable XML file has to be created inside the *res/drawable* folder.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to use Camera translate function to do.

```
 Camera mCamera = new Camera();
 mCamera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, -295.0f);
```

I am not sure but i think it help you.

Thanks